# Shortest sequence of nodes though an unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, shortest-path

I would like to know if there is an algorithm for finding the shortest sequence of nodes though a graph from its a head node to the tail node. The graph branches out from the head node and is arbitrarily complex and converges at the tail node. All connections between nodes are unweighted.

I'm considering tackling this problem taking exploratory steps from the head and tail nodes and until the nodes from either end of the graph touch etc, but I'd like to know if a "better wheel" exists before I (re)invent one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), which runs in O(E+V). It's the fastest you'll get on an unweighted graph.

Comment: Thanks. The approach that I have in mind is a breadth first search but bidirectional i.e. starting from both ends of the graph. To clarify, I am not interested in all paths in the graph, just the one(s) that that pass though the smallest number of nodes.

Comment: @Olumide BFS from the start and stop when you reach the end node. This will get you the smallest number of nodes. No need to branch out from both ends.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579399/shortest-path-fewest-nodes-for-unweighted-graph for Java code.

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought tracing from both ends would prevent the search from becoming as broad as the graph -- in the case of a very broad graph.

Comment: @Olumide As long as you don't revisit nodes (mark nodes visited as in the linked question) then you're guaranteed to process each node at most once, which is pretty fast. Branching from each end might make it slightly faster in some cases, but unless your graphs have very specific traits its not going to help much on average. You could always implement both and compare runtimes.

Comment: Not true - starting from one end requires visiting all nodes with distance <= the distance to the final node. Starting at both ends only requires visiting nodes that are <= half the distance from either end. On a euclidean graph, for example, this is half as many nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the beautiful "standard" problems of computer science.  Given your description of the graph, you should first look at [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Dijkstra's is O(E+VlogV) and more complicated to implement than BFS, which works for unweighted graphs.

Comment: You are correct for the general case.  In the case of unweighted graphs, the priority queue in Dijkstra's algorithm can be replaced with an ordinary queue and then the algorithm is as efficient as a breadth first search.  I didn't make that optimization clear.

Answer (score 0):

BFS is the best for these types of problems, even if you want to find out single node shortest path you have traverse whole graph for finding if there any other possible path other than the already obtained shortest path.

You can also draw a BFS Tree which will tell you exactly the shortest route between source and any(also single) node.