# Program to find whether the destination is reachable or not

Tags: java

I was asked in an interview the below question

Given a list of Flights and a starting point and destination print out all possible combination of flights which can be used to reach destination from starting point.

example :
Given the list of flights like

```
A -> B
A -> D
B -> C
B -> D
B -> H
D -> A
C -> E
E -> F
E -> G
G -> H
```

Given start point as A and endpoint as H the program should output

A -> B -> H

A -> B -> C -> E -> G -> H

The program I wrote is like below

```
package flight;

import java.util.List;

public class Flights {

    private String start;
    private List<String> destinations;

    public Flights(String start, List<String> destinations) {
        this.start = start;
        this.destinations = destinations;
    }

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public List<String> getDestinations() {
        return destinations;
    }

    public void setDestinations(List<String> destinations) {
        this.destinations = destinations;
    }

    public boolean containsDestination(String city){
        return getDestinations().contains(city);
    }
}

package flight;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("B");
        fList.add("D");
        Flights f1 = new Flights("A",fList);

        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("C");
        fList.add("D");
        fList.add("H");
        Flights f2 = new Flights("B",fList);

        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("A");
        Flights f3 = new Flights("D",fList);


        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("E");
        Flights f4 = new Flights("C",fList);

        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("F");
        fList.add("G");
        Flights f5 = new Flights("E",fList);

        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("H");
        Flights f6 = new Flights("G",fList);

        List<Flights> flights = new ArrayList<>();
        flights.add(f1);
        flights.add(f2);
        flights.add(f3);
        flights.add(f4);
        flights.add(f5);
        flights.add(f6);

        String start = "A";
        String end = "H";

        getFlights(flights,start,end,end);

    }


    private static void getFlights(List<Flights> flights,String start,String destination,String flightResult){
        if (start.equals(destination)){
             flightResult = flightResult+"-"+start;
        }
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<flights.size();i++){
            Flights f = flights.get(i);
            if(f.containsDestination(destination)){
                ls.add(flightResult+"-"+f.getStart());
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<ls.size();i++){
            String as = ls.get(i);
            String[] s = as.split("-");
            String lastCity = s[s.length-1];
            if (!lastCity.equals(start)){
                getFlights(flights,start,lastCity,as);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(ls);
    }
}
```

The program is outputting like

```
[H-B-A]
[H-G-E-C-B-A]
[H-G-E-C-B]
[H-G-E-C]
[H-G-E]
[H-B, H-G]
```

I only want the first two ones which are valid, how can i do that ?
Also is there an optimized way ?

Comment: Try to think in the recursive direction, or read about BFS implementation. This is a classic problem, no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: your algorithm is not efficient and would ground to a very slow execution for sizeable graphs. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528962/shortest-sequence-of-nodes-though-an-unweighted-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has problem with

```
if (!lastCity.equals(start)){
     getFlights(flights,start,lastCity,as);
}
```

After returning from the recursive call it still has `System.out.println(ls)` below it, So it print's everything you save in the list, you can overcome this problem by having your result stored in another list, i checked it's working, here's the code and i mentioned changes in the code with side comments, you need to change only your test class

```
package flight;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("B");
        fList.add("D");
        Flights f1 = new Flights("A",fList);

        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("C");
        fList.add("D");
        fList.add("H");
        Flights f2 = new Flights("B",fList);

        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("A");
        Flights f3 = new Flights("D",fList);


        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("E");
        Flights f4 = new Flights("C",fList);

        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("F");
        fList.add("G");
        Flights f5 = new Flights("E",fList);

        fList = new ArrayList<>();
        fList.add("H");
        Flights f6 = new Flights("G",fList);

        List<Flights> flights = new ArrayList<>();
        flights.add(f1);
        flights.add(f2);
        flights.add(f3);
        flights.add(f4);
        flights.add(f5);
        flights.add(f6);

        String start = "A";
        String end = "H";

        getFlights(flights,start,end,end);

        for(int i=0;i<answerlist.size();i++){   // print here
            String s = answerlist.get(i);
            StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder(); // stringbuilder to reverse the result
            x.append(s);
            x = x.reverse();
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    public static List<String> answerlist = new ArrayList<>();   //list to store result

    private static void getFlights(List<Flights> flights,String start,String destination,String flightResult){
        if (start.equals(destination)){
             flightResult = flightResult+"-"+start;
        }
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<flights.size();i++){
            Flights f = flights.get(i);
            if(f.containsDestination(destination)){
                ls.add(flightResult+"-"+f.getStart());
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<ls.size();i++){
            String as = ls.get(i);
            String[] s = as.split("-");
            String lastCity = s[s.length-1];
            if (!lastCity.equals(start)){
                getFlights(flights,start,lastCity,as);
            }
            else{
                answerlist.add(as);        //store in a newlist
            }       
        }
    }
}
```