# Find the minimal common path from any nodes to one node

Tags: python, path, shortest

My problem is the following.

I have a "*backup*" node and others nodes.
From theses nodes, I need to generate a common path to the backup node which is minimal (unweighted and undirected graph)
I don't need a solution everytime. Just how I can know if I can generate this path or not.

I was thinking about splitting the graph into some sub-graphs and searching for minimal "*subpath*".

But I'm not so good in graph theory.
I use Python and C++.

Thanks you from advance.

(Sorry If there is already a question like this, I have searched, but not found)

Comment: You want to construct a minimal spanning tree from your graph, with the backup node as the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you need to find a node with a minimal distance to the "backup" node, then BFS would be appropriate.
- As I understood, you need to find a minimal path from several( if not all) noes in your graph to the "backup" node. 
  For that, I think, you need to look into algorithms that deal with [Minimum Spanning Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)
- Also, I've found another StackOverflow question that resembles yours:
  [SO#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579399/shortest-path-fewest-nodes-for-unweighted-graph)
- You may also find this page useful:
  [Shortest Path Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_tree). It doesn't provide any code samples, but it is a starting point. Once you get the theory behind it, I am sure you will either come up with code or will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is not about "shortest", it's about whether they are connected or not.

you can do `bfs` or `dfs` starting from the "backup" node, each node you've reached can generate a path to the "backup" node.

check out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: But it need to be common to each nodes. If I do only a BFS, I can have the path from "backup" node to each node. Not a common path for all nodes to the "backup" node.