# Find the length of the shortest instruction string from all nodes to one node

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

We have a set of nodes which are connected in a circle, with one additional one-way connection from one node to another. The set of instructions is composed of `F`, going one node clockwise, `B` going one node counter-clockwise, and `P`, going through the one-way connection.

Each node has a one-way connection to a node (which can be itself). Each connection can go on the same node than the connection of the node before it, or further (the nodes and the ones on the other side of the connections are in the same order). I need to find the length of the shortest instruction set which can move to the first node, no matter the starting node.

I have already tried looking for chains of connections ending in a node which connects to itself, since it is where everything should converge, but after that first convergence I haven't found any optimized way of determining the shortest path to the next "best" convergence. I didn't find anything about this on the internet and I'm running short of ideas. I think there's a mathematical theorem behind this but I can't find any.

I have already looked at Minimum Spanning Trees ([Find the minimal common path from any nodes to one node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290527/find-the-minimal-common-path-from-any-nodes-to-one-node)), but those doesn't fit since I have a set of instructions.

EDIT : An example.

Suppose that we have the following data : `0 1 0 0` (that means that the connection of the first node goes 0 nodes forward, the second one goes 1 node forward, etc.). This can be drawn that way (I'm omitting the links between each node) :

```
o--o
|  | <------------ Those are "dead" nodes
|  V
o--1     2
         |
         V    <--- This is a "convergence chain"
o--4     3--o
|  ^     ^  |
|  |     |  |
o--o     o--o
```

Here, the solution is `PBPBPFF` (or `PBPBPBB`). Here we are using the convergence chain as a mean to group them, and then we shift them to the first node.

Comment: Sounds too crazy. Is this some practical application or is this homework?

Comment: It is homework, but it is possible. I'm not asking for code, I just don't have any info on this kind of problem at all.

Comment: If there's 4 nodes in a circle 1-2-3-4, and the one-way connection goes from 1-3, can you say what the solution is? Or is the problem not always soluble?

Comment: Could you give some example drawings of instruction series and their corresponding paths? Because I must misunderstand as I think spanning trees are exactly what you need.

Comment: Is there 1 one-way connection, or 1 from every node?

Comment: I've made an edit with a drawing to make this a bit easier to understand. @Noctua the problem with spanning trees is that they don't have instructions with directions, they can go in any direction they want, whereas in this problem all the nodes need to follow the same instructions, therefore directions.

Comment: Under PBPBPFF, 1->1->4->4->3->3->4->1, but 2->2->1->3->2->2->3->4. So your solution doesn't work (and if I understand the problem, which I quite probably don't, there's no solution).

Comment: @Anonymous yes, sorry i thought the connection was between 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the length of the circle is N. On the input, we've also got an array C[N].
There are three possible operations for a position P:

```
a) p = (p - 1) % N
b) p = (p + 1) % N
c) p = (p + C[p]) % N
```

Let's try try decompose the problem a bit. First, let's try to find a chain that takes positions P, Q to the same position R.

We'll soon find out that getting the two positions "closer" to each other won't take more than O(N) steps. If we perform N steps and the two positions are still at the same distance, we should rather use simple rotation, which would take at most N/2 steps.
From this observation, if it's possible, a simple BFS finds a solution in O(N^2). If the solution isn't found in N^2 steps, the solution doesn't exist. Now, using this chain, move all input positions, pick another two and find a solution for them. In the end, we end up with a single position, converting of which to the initial position is trivial. So if there's any solution to the problem, this algorithm will find it at

```
O(
   N - n positions 
   * 
   (N^2 - merge two positions to one
    + 
    N * N^2 - recalculate the positions with chain we've just found
   )
 )
```

, which is at most N^3 commands (each applied N times).

Now, we can simply BFS a graph of all possible combinations.

Starting with ("", [0..n]), we can loop through the queue and push new three items according to our commands (if the positions weren't find yet) :

```
(commands, [p1, p2, ... pn]) ->
    (commands + "F", [(p1 + 1) % N, ... (pn + 1) % N])
    (commands + "B", [(p1 - 1) % N, ... (pn - 1) % N])
    (commands + "P", [(p1 + C[p1]) % N, ... (pn + C[pn]) % N])
```

We terminate either when the vector is filled with zeros or if we've performed enough steps so that a solution cannot be found. The boundaries could be possibly improved, but it should be clear that these I've mentioned work.

Comment: Can you find the shortest solution using this algorithm ? That's the main problem I've been facing with my others solutions, because I don't know whether it will find __the__ shortest path or just one solution which could be improved.

Comment: The BFS will find the shortest solution. The first part is just to show that it's fine to terminate the algorithm if it doesn't find any solution soon enough and tell that the solution doesn't exist. In fact, it shouldn't be even needed - the BFS would terminate due to an empty queue.