# Find shortest path between two locations (Unweighted & Using BFS)

Tags: java, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

**SHORTEST PATH USING BFS**

```
public static LinkedList<String> findShortestPath(String start, String end) {

    LinkedList<String> bfsList = new LinkedList<String>();
    Queue<Actor> queue = new LinkedList<Actor>();
    Map<String, Actor> prev = new HashMap<String, Actor>();
    Actor current = graph.getActorsByName().get(start);

    queue.add(current);
    current.setVisited(true);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {

        current = queue.remove();;

        if(current.getName().equals(end)) {

            break;

        } else {

            for(int i = 0; i < current.getFriends().size(); i++) {

                if(current.getFriends().get(i).getVisited() == false) {

                    queue.add(graph.getActorsByName().get(current.getFriends().get(i).getName()));
                    graph.getActorsByName().get(current.getFriends().get(i).getName()).setVisited(true);
                    prev.put(current.getFriends().get(i).getName(), current);

                }

            }

        }

    }

    if(!current.getName().equals(end)) {

        System.out.println("\nThere is no path between " + start + " and " + end);

    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Actor> entry : prev.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();
        bfsList.add(key);

    }

    return bfsList;

}
```

Above is the code I'm using to try and find the shortest path between two points in a graph. It isn't giving me the correct path between the two points, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working correctly? Do you have test inputs? Any expected outputs and actual outputs? And do you have any references that you have based your implementation on?

Comment: @James Yes, I do have a couple of test inputs and an expected output; but for that to make any sense here I would have to put up my entire program which is 1000+ lines... I just want to know if the method I provided would give me the shortest path between two points.

The reference I used for this implementation was this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579399/shortest-path-fewest-nodes-for-unweighted-graph

I'm just having some trouble understanding the algorithm behind finding the shortest path using Breadth First Search, specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set up a test rig, where I expect an actor to have a name and some friends. Those immediate friends also have a reciprocal relationship.

In this test I am looking for the shortest path between "james" and "mary".

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ShortestPathTest {

    Map<String, ShortestPath.Actor> graph = new HashMap<>();

    private ShortestPath.Actor newActor(String name, String... friends) {
        ShortestPath.Actor actor = graph.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new ShortestPath.Actor(name));
        for(String friendsName : friends) {
            ShortestPath.Actor friend = newActor(friendsName);
            actor.addFriend(friend);
            friend.addFriend(actor);
        }
        return actor;
    }

    @Test
    public void findShortestPath() {
        newActor("james", "harry", "luke", "john");
        newActor("harry", "luke", "mary");

        LinkedList<String> shortestPath = ShortestPath.findShortestPath(graph, "james", "mary");
        assertThat(shortestPath, equalTo(Arrays.asList("james", "harry", "mary")));
    }
}
```

The result I received was not consistent with my expectations and for some reason "mary" is in the middle of the output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <[james, harry, mary]>
     but: was <[luke, harry, mary, john]>
```

Comparing the [algorithm you have referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579508/7421645), I suspect the issue is in this part (of the referenced algorithm):

```
for(Node node = finish; node != null; node = prev.get(node)) {
    directions.add(node);
}
directions.reverse();
```

In your implementation you have initialised `prev = new HashMap<String, Actor>()` and you are then adding every visited node (not just the nodes to indicate the shortest path). You need to use `prev` as sort of linked list... for example:

```
    for (Actor node = graph.get(end); node != null; node = prev.get(node.getName())) {
        bfsList.add(node.getName());
    }
    Collections.reverse(bfsList);
```

---

## Full updated code for testing purposes

### shortest path implementation

Only minor edits applied to original posting:

- Input `graph` as parameter
- Simplified logic in the inner loop by extracting looked at variable
- Returns empty list if no path can be found
- Fixed loop of hash map that analysed the shortest path found
- Added Actor class for testing

**code listing**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

public class ShortestPath {

    public static List<String> findShortestPath(Map<String, Actor> graph, String start,
        String end) {

        LinkedList<String> bfsList = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Actor> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Map<String, Actor> prev = new HashMap<>();
        Actor current = graph.get(start);

        queue.add(current);
        current.setVisited(true);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {

            current = queue.remove();

            if (current.getName().equals(end)) {
                break;
            } else {
                LinkedList<Actor> currentFriends = current.getFriends();
                for (Actor currentFriend : currentFriends) {
                    if (!currentFriend.getVisited()) {
                        queue.add(currentFriend);
                        currentFriend.setVisited(true);
                        prev.put(currentFriend.getName(), current);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!current.getName().equals(end)) {
            System.out.println("\nThere is no path between " + start + " and " + end);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        for (Actor node = graph.get(end); node != null; node = prev.get(node.getName())) {
            bfsList.add(node.getName());
        }
        Collections.reverse(bfsList);

        return bfsList;

    }

    static class Actor {

        private final String name;
        private final LinkedList<Actor> friends = new LinkedList<>();

        private boolean visited;

        Actor(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
            this.visited = visited;
        }

        // Would normally be `isVisited`
        public boolean getVisited() {
            return visited;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public LinkedList<Actor> getFriends() {
            return friends;
        }

        public void addFriend(Actor actor) {
            this.friends.add(actor);
        }
    }
}
```

### Test code

Builds test graph and asserts the correct path is found between various nodes

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ShortestPathTest {

    Map<String, ShortestPath.Actor> graph = new HashMap<>();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        newActor("james", "harry", "luke", "john");
        newActor("harry", "luke", "mary");
        newActor("luke", "john", "hepzibah");
        newActor("john", "kate");
        newActor("mary", "hepzibah", "mia");
        newActor("hepzibah", "richard");
        newActor("kate", "martin", "mia");
        newActor("mia", "susan");
        newActor("richard", "rebecca");
        newActor("rebecca", "hannah");
        newActor("michelle");
    }

    private ShortestPath.Actor newActor(String name, String... friends) {
        ShortestPath.Actor actor = graph.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new ShortestPath.Actor(name));
        for (String friendsName : friends) {
            ShortestPath.Actor friend = newActor(friendsName);
            actor.addFriend(friend);
            friend.addFriend(actor);
        }
        return actor;
    }

    @Test
    public void findShortestPath() {
        List<String> shortestPath = ShortestPath.findShortestPath(graph, "james", "mary");
        assertThat(shortestPath, equalTo(Arrays.asList("james", "harry", "mary")));
    }

    @Test
    public void findLongerShortestPath() {
        List<String> shortestPath = ShortestPath.findShortestPath(graph, "james", "mia");
        assertThat(shortestPath, equalTo(Arrays.asList("james", "harry", "mary", "mia")));
    }

    @Test
    public void findAnotherShortestPath() {
        List<String> shortestPath = ShortestPath.findShortestPath(graph, "harry", "hannah");
        assertThat(shortestPath, equalTo(Arrays.asList("harry", "luke", "hepzibah", "richard", "rebecca", "hannah")));
    }

    @Test
    public void findNoPath() {
        List<String> shortestPath = ShortestPath.findShortestPath(graph, "james", "michelle");
        assertThat(shortestPath, equalTo(Collections.emptyList()));
    }
}
```